# clearRect with SetInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Below my code

```js
var canvas, context;
var canvas = document.getElementById('board');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var hex = 50;

function drawHex(hexGain) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if (hexGain <= 0) return;
  x = canvas.width / 2 - hexGain;
  y = canvas.height / 2;
  context.moveTo(x, y);
  x += hexGain / 2;
  y -= hexGain / 2;
  context.lineTo(x, y); // now render it per our style definitions
  x += hexGain;
  y += 0;
  context.lineTo(x, y);
  x += hexGain / 2;
  y += hexGain / 2;
  context.lineTo(x, y);
  x -= hexGain / 2;
  y += hexGain / 2;
  context.lineTo(x, y);
  x -= hexGain;
  y += 0;
  context.lineTo(x, y);
  x -= hexGain / 2;
  y -= hexGain / 2;
  context.lineTo(x, y);
  context.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
  context.stroke();
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  drawHex(hex);
  hex -= 5;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="board"></canvas>
```

I'm not able to draw and hexagon, wait a second, clear the canvas, draw a smaller one and so on.
I don't understand why the clearRect is not invoked.
I basically need an animation of an hexagon which is smaller and smaller

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `context.beginPath()` when you start drawing.

So what's happening is that the canvas is indeed clearing, but you're adding a second hexagon to the "path" that is being drawn. Then another, and another.